# C compiler error: "comparison between a pointer and an integer".

Tags: c, compiler-errors, scanf

I've done a few programs in the past few days using fscanf() but haven't received this error. It's on line 21 at the while loop condition statement. The program takes the second argument passed from the console, which is a file containing a very large mersenne prime number, and reads the contents into the program. From there I'm adding up the total count of the digits as well as the count of each different possible digit (i.e. 0, 1, 2, etc.) and then printing the results to the console. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        FILE *file;
        int digit;
        unsigned long int zeros = 0;
        unsigned long int ones = 0;
        unsigned long int twos = 0;
        unsigned long int threes = 0;
        unsigned long int fours = 0;
        unsigned long int fives = 0;
        unsigned long int sixes = 0;
        unsigned long int sevens = 0;
        unsigned long int eights = 0;
        unsigned long int nines = 0;
        unsigned long int total = 0;

        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        while (fscanf(file, "%d", &digit) != NULL)
        {
                if (digit == 0)
                {
                        zeros += 1;
                }

                else if (digit == 1)
                {
                        ones += 1;
                }
                else if (digit == 2)
                {
                        twos += 1;
                }
                else if (digit == 3)
                {
                        threes += 1;
                }
                else if (digit == 4)
                {
                        fours += 1;
                }
                else if (digit == 5)
                {
                        fives += 1;
                }
                else if (digit == 6)
                {
                        sixes += 1;
                }
                else if (digit == 7)
                {
                        sevens += 1;
                }
                else if (digit == 8)
                {
                        eights += 1;
                }
                else if (digit == 9)
                {
                        nines += 1;
                }
                total += 1;
        }

        printf("0s: %u\n1s: %u\n2s: %u\n3s: %u\n4s: %u\n5s: %u\n6s: %u\n7s: %u\n8s: %u\n9s: %u\nTotal: %u\n", zeros, ones, twos, threes, fours, fives, sixes, sevens, eights, nines, total);

        fclose(file);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: note: you could simplify your code greatly: `unsigned long int counts[10] = { 0 };` ... `if ( digit >= 0 && digit < 10 ) counts[digit] += 1;`

Comment: If you want to read a single digit from a string of adjacent digits, then `%d` will not work: that treats all adjacent digits as one large number (causing undefined behaviour if the number is too big for an `int`).   You would need to use `%c` to read one character at a time (and bear in mind that the resulting value will be in the range `'0'` to `'9'`).

Comment: @M.M Thanks a lot for the suggestions. Here's what I changed:

Comment: It wouldn't let me post the code here so I just edited the original post. Thanks again.

Comment: In the updated code, `atoi(input)` is an error. The `atoi` function expects a null-terminated string but you did not provide one. You could either add a null terminator, or change the line to `digit = input[0] - '0'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `fscanf` is `int`. Hence, the compiler complains about using:

```
    while (fscanf(file, "%d", &digit) != NULL)
```

Change it to:

```
    while (fscanf(file, "%d", &digit) == 1)
```

Comment: @R Sahu Thanks for the help. That did indeed allow the program to compile. I do have one more question if you don't mind. The individual digit counts are all displaying zero in the output. Why don't the counters continue to add up the sum of the count?

Comment: @seeuuaye08, the variables are of type `unsigned long int`. You should use the format `%lu` instead of `%u` to print them.

Comment: @seeuuaye08 I think my second comment to your main question would explain why your counts are all zero

Comment: @R Sahu I've edited it and it's still producing a zero value for each digit

Comment: @seeuuaye08, looks like you are seeing the problem that M.M warned you about. You can add a `printf` line to print `digit` to help you debug the problem.

Comment: @R Sahu Yeah I printed digit after the while loop and it was something like 5,000,000. So it looks like it's not taking each digit one at a time like I was hoping. I'll try M.M's solution.